# Rails / Paperclip attaching via command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a bunch of jpeg files in a folder on my server, and I'm attempting to attach them to their corresponding `Property` instances through a rake task.

`property.rb` has the following code:

```
  has_attached_file :temp_photo,
    :styles => PropertyImage::STYLES,
    :url => "/assets/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :path => "#{Rails.root}/public/assets/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

I use paperclip on other models, and there are no issues whatsoever, but I get a problem when I attempt the following:

```
p = Property.find(id)
file = File.open(temp_file_path)
p.temp_photo = file
p.save

# => false

file.close
p.errors

# => "/tmp/stream20110524-1126-1cunv0y-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command."
```

The file definitely exists, and I've tried changing the permissions. Restarting the server doesn't help. The problem seems to be with using the command line, as the normal form / HTTP approach works fine. This is only a temporary set-up, so I'm looking for a working way to import a batch of files into my rails app paperclip model.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996102/rails-paperclip-and-passenger-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify-command)

Comment: Nope, I've tried that already, it seemed to make no difference. As I said, it works fine when I add images over apache - the problem is in a rake task / console.

Comment: Are you sure that the image is a correct one? What happens if you manually invoke `identify /tmp/stream2011....`? Maybe some newer version will work for you - I can without problems import files with paperclip 2.4.0

Answer (score 5):

```
path = 'target_file_path'
attach_name = 'temp_photo'

p = Property.find(id)
attach = Paperclip::Attachment.new(attach_name, p, p.class.attachment_definitions[attach_name.to_suym])

file = File.open(path) 
attach.assign file
attach.save

file.close
```

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397461/how-to-set-file-programmatically-using-paperclip

Comment: .to_suym  should be .to_sym