# bson_dump error when try to attach a file to mongoid paperclip field of a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip

I have spent a lot of time trying to attach a file into a mongoid paperclip field. The examples that I have found, always do the same:

```
my_model_instance = MyModel.new
file = File.open(file_path)
my_model_instance.attachment = file
file.close
my_model_instance.save!
```

as you can see in [How to set a file upload programmatically using Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397461/how-to-set-file-programmatically-using-paperclip).

The model that I have done is:

```
class Logotype
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Paperclip

    has_mongoid_attached_file :logo,
      styles: {large: ['640x160'], small: ['300x300>']},
      size: { in: 0..3.megabytes },
      content_type: [ "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/bmp" ],
      storage: :filesystem,
      path: ':rails_root/public/resource/resources/:id/:style.:extension',
      url: '/logos/resources/:id/:style.:extension'

    validates_presence_of :logo
    validates_uniqueness_of :logo
end
```

However I have always the same big error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `__bson_dump__' for /logos/resources/51b5bfaa69fd8a7941000005/original.jpg?1370865578:Paperclip::Attachment
...
```

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

PD: Sorry for my English level.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just thought I'd share my solution in case someone else finds themselves here.

For me, this was happening in the `Moped::BSON::Extensions::Hash` module while trying to log the request for a save action. Your stack may be different, but basically the problem occurs when trying to dump data that Mongoid doesn't know how to handle. In my case it was a file upload, `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, but for the OP it's a `Paperclip::Attachment`.

I solved it by just removing those key/value pairs from the request parameters, e.g.

```
   # recursively remove UploadedFile from a Hash of request parameters 
   def remove_files(params)
      p = proc do |_, v|
        v.delete_if(&p) if v.respond_to? :delete_if
        v.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)
      end
      params.delete_if(&p)
    end
```

There might be a better solution that logs the filename or something instead, but I found it easier just to get rid of it.